# Handling duplicate entries in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have an app that allows users to save favorites. I am using Core Data to store the favorites as managed objects. I have written some code to prevent the possibility of storing duplicates, but am wondering if there is a better way to do so. Each favorite object has an ID field that is unique. In the following code I am simply looping through and checking the ID field, and if the value already exists, setting a flag value to true, and breaking out of the loop.

```
-(BOOL)addFavorite{
    BOOL entityExists = NO;
    if(context){
        // does this favorite already exist?
        NSArray *allFaves = [AppDataAccess getAllFavorites];
        for(Favorite *f in allFaves){
            if([f.stationIdentifier isEqualToString:stID]){
                entityExists = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!entityExists){
            NSError *err = nil;
            Favorite *fave = [Favorite insertInManagedObjectContext:context];
            fave.stationRealName = riverGauge.name;
            fave.stationIdentifier = stID;
            fave.stationState = @"WV";
            if(![context save:&err]){
                NSLog(@"ERROR: Could not save context--%@", err);
            }
            return YES;            
        }
    return NO;
}
```

I was wondering if Core Data has the ability to check to see if an object being added is a duplicate. Is there a predicate that can handle checking for duplicates? Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

CoreData does no uniquing by itself. It has no notion of two entries being identical.

To enable such a behavior you have to implement it yourself by doing a 'search before insert' aka a 'fetch before create'.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Favorite"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"stationIdentifier == %@", stID];
[fetch setPredicate:predicate];
YourObject *obj = [ctx executeRequest:fetch];

if(!obj) {
    //not there so create it and save
    obj = [ctx insertNewManagedObjectForEntity:@"Favorite"]; //typed inline, dont know actual method
    obj.stationIdentifier = stID;
    [ctx save];
}

//use obj... e.g.
NSLog(@"%@", obj.stationIdentifier);
```

#### Remember this assumes single-threaded access

Answer (score 13):

Just an update since iOS 9.0 you can do it easily with "unique constraints" in the model. But pay attention - if your store already contains duplicates , core data will fail any auto migration when the app shipped.

See here for example - [core data unique constraints](http://dorianroy.com/blog/2015/09/how-to-implement-unique-constraints-in-core-data-with-ios-9/)

Comment: How to handle migration ?

Comment: Unique constraints are not supported with CloudKit and are forbidden in iOS 14

Comment: to clarify FontFamily's comment see https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656380 Cloudkit != NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4**

```
func isEntityAttributeExist(id: Int, entityName: String) -> Bool {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id)
    let res = try! managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    return res.count > 0 ? true : false
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3**:

```
func isExist(id: Int) -> Bool {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: myEntityName)
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %d", argumentArray: id)

    let res = try! theContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    return res.count > 0 ? true : false
}
```

Comment: what is theContext here?

Comment: @amish , it’s an instance of ‘NSManagedObjectContext’

Comment: @Vahid `let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext`, this is what I am defining context. is it right? I am getting an error on the line `let res = try! theContext.fetch(fetchRequest)`.

Comment: just return "res.count > 0", don't need to add "true : false". they have already been a Boolean.

Answer (score 4):

> I was wondering if Core Data has the ability to check to see if an object being added is a duplicate.

No, Core Data doesn't care about that.

> Is there a predicate that can handle checking for duplicates?

Since your objects have unique IDs that you control, do a fetch for an existing favorite with that ID. Something like

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Favorite"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"stationIdentifier == %@", stID];
[fetch setPredicate:predicate];
```

If you get any results, you know that a favorite with that ID already exists. And, you have a reference to that favorite in case you want to change it.

Your current approach is fine and probably faster if there are only a few favorites. Doing a fetch will scale better to lots of favorites.

Answer (score 3):

If you're dealing with multiple records, iterating over a count fetch or retrieving actual objects is VERY costly on the CPU. In my case, I did one fetch for all matching records, but asked for a dictionary of just the string of the UUID back. Saves a lot of CPU overhead.

For example, I have a uUID property on every record in core data. I have a corresponding UUID listed as @"UUID" in CloudKit.

```
  //1. Create a request for the entity type, returning an array of dictionaries  
      NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"someEntityName"];
      [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
      [request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
      [request setPropertiesToFetch: @[@"uUID"]];

  //2. Create an array of UUID strings of the downloaded objects
      NSMutableArray *UUIDstrings = [NSMutableArray new];
      for (CKRecord *record in ckRecords) {
        [UUIDstrings addObject:record[@"UUID"]];
      }

   //3. Create a predicate to find any Core Data objects with the same UUID
      [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uUID in %@", UUIDstrings]];

   //4. If there are results from the fetch, do a log and you'll see it's a dictionary. 
      NSArray *deck = [self.MOC executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

      NSLog(@"Logging the result of index 0. Should be a dictionary %@", deck.count > 0 ? [deck objectAtIndex:0] : @"No results");

   //5. Then either do an embedded fast enumeration (for xx in xx){for xx in xx} to find a match like         

           if ([(NSString *)record[@"UUID"] isEqualToString:[dict valueForKey:@"uUID"]]) 
          {do something}

   //...Or 6. Use a more linear approach with NSSet

    //Harvest the core data strings
      NSMutableArray *coreDataStrings = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (NSDictionary *dict in deck) {
        [coreDataStrings addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"uUID"]];
      }

   //Create a set of your downloaded objects
      NSSet *arraySet = [NSSet setWithArray:ckRecords];

   //Then use a predicate search - a NOT version of above
     NSArray *final = [[arraySet filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT(UUID in %@)", coreDataStrings]]allObjects];
```

The console log of the dictionary will look something like this. Just the smallest amount of info required to match:

```
dictionary {
   uUID = "AFACB8CE-B29E-4A03-9284-4BD5F5464";
}
```

[More here at the developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html) on finding unique values.